# Google Dataflow Python Apache Beam Windowing delay issue

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a simple pipeline that receives data from PubSub, prints it and then at every 10 seconds fires a window into a GroupByKey and prints that message again.

However this window seems to be delaying sometimes. Is this a google limitation or is there something wrong with my code:

```
 with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipe:
        messages = (
            pipe
            | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_subscription).with_output_types(bytes)
            | 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
            | 'Ex' >> beam.ParDo(ExtractorAndPrinter())
            | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(10), allowed_lateness=0, accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING, trigger=AfterProcessingTime(10) )
            | 'group' >> beam.GroupByKey()
            | 'PRINTER' >> beam.ParDo(PrinterWorker()))
```

[image]

Edit for the most recent code. I removed the triggers however the problem persists:

```
class ExtractorAndCounter(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        beam.DoFn.__init__(self)

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        import logging
        logging.info(element)
        return [("Message", json.loads(element)["Message"])]

class PrinterWorker(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self):
        beam.DoFn.__init__(self)

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        import logging
        logging.info(element)
        return [str(element)]


class DefineTimestamp(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        from datetime import datetime
        return [(str(datetime.now()), element)]

def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    """Build and run the pipeline."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
      '--output_topic',
      required=True,
      help=(
          'Output PubSub topic of the form '
          '"projects/<PROJECT>/topics/<TOPIC>".'))
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument(
      '--input_topic',
      help=(
          'Input PubSub topic of the form '
          '"projects/<PROJECT>/topics/<TOPIC>".'))
    group.add_argument(
      '--input_subscription',
      help=(
          'Input PubSub subscription of the form '
          '"projects/<PROJECT>/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION>."'))
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)

pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
pipeline_options.view_as(StandardOptions).streaming = True
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipe:
    messages = (
        pipe
        | beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.input_subscription).with_output_types(bytes)
        | 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'))
        | 'Ex' >> beam.ParDo(ExtractorAndCounter())
        | beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(10))
        | 'group' >> beam.GroupByKey()
        | 'PRINTER' >> beam.ParDo(PrinterWorker())
        | 'encode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'))
        | beam.io.WriteToPubSub(known_args.output_topic))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

Comment: Did you try not specifying a trigger?

Comment: Yep I did, same issue.

Comment: May you provide the whole code so I can try to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @rmesteves here ya go

Comment: I reproduced your problem and have similar results. Can you explain me exactly what is your problem?  I mean, which delay is in fact bothering you?

Comment: While testing locally this exact code would print out results at exactly every 10 seconds, like clockwork, however with google cloud dataflow I get results that vary between 8 and 12 seconds, I'm just trying to figure out if this is some issue with the way the code is written of it's a platform limitation/logging delay/ pubsub delay/etc

Comment: So the problem is not in the message itself but in the time it is delivered? I mean, is the data inside the messages the correct window data?

Comment: Actually, the delivery is happening in the correct time. I reproduced your issue and realized that the "timestamp"property is about the time when the window was initialized and not the time when the window was flushed to the logging. Can you open your logs and check the receiveTimestamp property? It should be as regular as your DirectRunner. Please let me know the results

Comment: Could you check that?

Answer (score 2):

So what this basically ask the pipeline to do is to group elements to 10 second windows and fire every window after 10 seconds have passed since the first element was received for each window (and discard the rest of the data for that window). Was that your intention ?

Assuming this was the case, note that triggering depends on the time elements were received by the system as well as the time the first element is received for each window. Probably this is why you are seeing some variation in your results.

I think if you need more consistent grouping for your elements you should use event time triggers instead of processing time triggers.

Comment: This might be a good solution. However answering to your first question, what we want is basically have a trigger every 10 seconds that groups all the data received within those 10 seconds and sends it off.

Answer (score 0):

All the triggers are based on best effort means they will be fired sometime after the specified duration, 10 sec in this case. Generally it happen close to the time specified but a few seconds delay is possible.

Also, the triggers are set for Key+Window. The window is derived from event time. 
It is possible that the first GBK pint at 10:30:04 is due to the first element which as at 10:29:52
The 2nd GBK print at 10:30:07 is due to the first element at 10:29:56

So it will be good to print the window and event timestamp for each element and then co-relate the data.

Comment: And how would I remove that setting? I want it to fire every 10 seconds whether we have data in there nor not, as in every 10 seconds it would release all the data that had accumulated inside that window, if there was no data it wouldn't send a thing really.

Comment: And how would I remove that setting? >> This is not a setting but how the system behave.  In your pipeline, data is going to be emitted roughly at 10s. You are right, if their is not data or a key+window then that's not going to get emitted.